# De-mystifying allowed values for a field in Azure DevOps based on values of another field or Rules?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When you create a work item such as Bug in Azure devops, the values that you would see in the drop down of say Reason field would depend on the value you select for State field. For e.g. see these screenshots (Template Agile, no customizations)

[image: allowed values based on State Field]

Then if you change the state, the allowed values change as shown

[image]

To make matters more confusing, these are just few of the values that are returned by the documented REST API

The given API returns

```
 "defaultValue": null,
        "allowedValues": [
          "Verified",
          "Not fixed",
          "Test Failed",
          "As Designed",
          "Cannot Reproduce",
          "Copied to Backlog",
          "Deferred",
          "Duplicate",
          "Fixed and verified",
          "Obsolete",
          "Fixed",
          "Investigation Complete",
          "Approved",
          "Investigate",
          "Resolved in error",
          "Reactivated",
          "Regression",
          "Build Failure",
          "New"
        ],
        "helpText": "The reason why the bug is in the current state",
        "alwaysRequired": false,
        "dependentFields": [
          {
            "referenceName": "System.State",
            "name": "State",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/nikhil/_apis/wit/fields/System.State"
          },
          {
            "referenceName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason",
            "name": "Resolved Reason",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/nikhil/_apis/wit/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason"
          }
        ],
        "referenceName": "System.Reason",
        "name": "Reason",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{project}/{templateid}/_apis/wit/fields/System.Reason"
      },
```

I am trying to figure out the right API or set of APIs that help demystify when to show what in the combo boxes, when to mark them read-only and when to let the user edit them.

The **Resolved Reason** Field is further interesting. For most parts it seems to simply copy the value from the Reason field, however the Rules API (see below) does not indicate this behaviour. It looks like what the Rules API returns does not match the behaviour that this field exhibits.

There is a concept of Rules mentioned in the REST API here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/rules/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#processrule

However this does not seem to give rules which specifically control "allowedValues" for fields based on value of another field as I explained above.

## Question:

1. Is there an API that can give a comprehensive set of rules for fields on a work item types including their allowedValues? For e.g. the Reason or Resolved Reason field depending on the choice of State field as shown above?

Comment: Hi ,Nikhil Merlin gave an excellent answer, can this solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Hugh while Merlin's answer is very detailed, it does not solve my problem. I know that this is driven from the XML process template. My question is - how can I do it without having access to the physical template via an API. If that API is about fetching the XML template and then parsing it even that will work.

Comment: @Nikhil, I know it is much better to get the XML process files with internet without accessing the physical template files. But we did not open the path which can for external user to access the hosted XML process files of VSTS. The only method is you need to use API to fetch it first, then using C# to phrase them. If you need any sample, or still has puzzle about this, just free to ask here:-)

Comment: Thanks Merlin, you are super helpful! The Azure DevOPS Web UI correctly uses the logic somehow to filter the allowedValues. Does that take it from XML directly? All I want is to somehow replicate the same functionality that the web UI has.

Comment: @Nikhil For web UI, we get then phrase them from the hosted template files directly. But, for external users, we haven’t open the hosted path to be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an API that can give a comprehensive set of rules for fields
>   on a work item types including their allowedValues? For e.g. the
>   Reason or Resolved Reason field depending on the choice of State field
>   as shown above?

First of all, I need to say, no, there is no such REST API to get the `Reason` value which depending on the `State` filed chosen. Since these are all not be documented, the best way for us to verify it is using the [Fiddler trace](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)(Fiddler can record all internet data between web application and internet).

---

*[As example, here I will use **Bug** work item to show that.]*

First, clear all the records in Fiddler => open the Bug work item in Azure Devops => press F12 in Fiddler to start record the data.

Change the work item state in Azure Devops(**Note: just change, do not save it**. "Save" belong to another operation). Then go Fiddler to see its internet records:

[image]

You will see that there only 2 event API, and these API are only used to post the action sign but not operate it. See the request body of first **POST** Event API:

[image]

You can see that it just used to post a sign about the State field has changed. That's why I say that there's no API to get the `Reason` value which depending on the `State` filed chosen, because our develop team did not use the script with API to achieve that.

---

Now, you should be very confusing that who is this action message to be sent to? Since the Reason field value listed is not controlled by the api, then who is in control?

The answer is **XML process template**.

In Azure Devops, the WIT are all controlled by XML template. You can find all rules such as the `Reason` field value listed depend on the `State` field changed, copy the value from the Reason field and etc.

I have uploaded the `Bug.xml` of process template into my github, you can refer to that code to analysis it: [Agile-process/Bug.xml](https://github.com/LiangMengdi/Agile-process/blob/master/Bug.xml) .

> For the `Reason` field value listed depend on the `State` field
>   changed.

```
  <FIELD name="Resolved Reason" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES>
      <LISTITEM value="As Designed" />
      <LISTITEM value="Cannot Reproduce" />
      <LISTITEM value="Deferred" />
      <LISTITEM value="Duplicate" />
      <LISTITEM value="Fixed" />
      <LISTITEM value="Fixed and verified" />
      <LISTITEM value="Obsolete" />
      <LISTITEM value="Copied to Backlog" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <HELPTEXT>The reason why the bug was resolved</HELPTEXT>
  </FIELD>
```

These are the xml code which control the Resolved Reason listed. I believe that you have got its logic. The message of event API we got from fiddler are get by the relevant WIT `*.xml`. Then the corresponding operation will be trigger and acted.

[image]

> For copy the value from the Reason field.

```
    <TRANSITION from="New" to="Resolved">
      <ACTIONS>
        <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin" />
      </ACTIONS>
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Fixed">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Fixed" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                <LISTITEM value="Fixed" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </DEFAULTREASON>
        <REASON value="Deferred">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Deferred" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                <LISTITEM value="Deferred" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="Duplicate">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Duplicate" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                <LISTITEM value="Duplicate" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="As Designed">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="As Designed" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                <LISTITEM value="As Designed" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="Cannot Reproduce">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Cannot Reproduce" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                <LISTITEM value="Cannot Reproduce" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="Obsolete">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Obsolete" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                <LISTITEM value="Obsolete" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
        <REASON value="Copied to Backlog">
          <FIELDS>
            <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason">
              <COPY from="value" value="Copied to Backlog" />
              <ALLOWEDVALUES>
                <LISTITEM value="Copied to Backlog" />
              </ALLOWEDVALUES>
            </FIELD>
          </FIELDS>
        </REASON>
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <COPY from="field" field="System.CreatedBy" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
```

This just a short section which about the copy value from the Reason field from the `xml` file of **Bug** work item.

In fact, you can find all process rules from these XML file which could not get with API(**Note**: I just mean the default process rule). If you want, I can share the completed XML files of process in my github.

Hope this could help you more clearly:-)

Comment: Hi Merlin I understand that this comes from the XML template. However the Azure DevOPS UI somehow parses this template and changes the allowed values of Reason field. If not an API, is there a way to do this programmatically like Azure DevOPS UI does (which is my question really). I think this comes down to - can you fetch the process template by an API call and parse it?

Comment: @Nikhil If this, of course it can, just a little complex. In addition, it need you use C# to read the XML data from process template. But first, it need you use API to export the template first. For this API, see this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/Processes/Export%20Process%20Template?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: @Nikhil  Note: for VSTS this API can only get the hosted XML process template. It could not get the inherited process templates

Comment: Hi Merlin, thanks again! As I have explained in my comment above, I am simply looking for a way to replicate the same functionality that Azure DevOPS Web UI has. When you select a value for Status or Reason, the other combo boxes filters out some values. I am trying to replicate it in a set of UI controls for generic users. In this method, the code will have to download zip files, unzip, read XML etc. at runtime. I dont think the web UI does that!

Comment: @Nikhil Yeah, certainly not. For azure devops web UI, there does not has the process of download template file then unzip it. Just for external users, you must have this step-fetch it down, then phrase it with script.

Comment: @Nikhil, Do you still have any other questions relate to this ticket? Please don’t hesitate to contact me if there is anything I can help.

Comment: Hi Merlin thanks for following up and apologies for the delay in replying. I understand that for external callers this functionality is not exposed. I will even accept any undocumented API that can help with this without having to download XMLs. Specifically needed because if our customers use our software with hosted Azure DevOPS, it won't even be able to download the official XML files!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an API that can give a comprehensive set of rules for fields
>   on a work item types including the allowedValues of say Reason field
>   depending on the choice of State field?

For this issue , you can use [Rules - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/rules/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) api to get it .

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/rules?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

I test with postman ,  the figure below is the result returned by my test.

[image]

By searching for keywords, we can get the rules of allowed values for Reason field depending on the choice of State field.

The processId parameter required in the api can be obtained through this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/processes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. That's a good approach however I was looking for more of a recommended or official way of achieving this. Would you know if there is any?

Comment: Hi Hugh. I looked more into it. It probably doesn't work that way. For instance for Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason field, the Rules list returns a number of values for different conditions. However when you create a bug using Visual Studio or Web Portal, the combo box only ever shows one value at a time.
Same setup exists for System.Reason field however the combo box on both web and visual studio shows multiple options for those. This is rather confusing!